# Some details about $\boldsymbol{R_P}$ has a unique maximal ideal prove

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

So the problem is this

> Let $R$   be a commutative ring and let $P$   be a prime ideal.
>
> Prove that the set of non-units in $R_{P}$   is the ideal $P_{P}$ , moreover  $R_{P}$ is a quasi local ring.

I searched and found this solution.

> The ideal $P_P$ is $$ P_P=\left\{\frac{a}{s}: a\in P, s\in R\setminus
>  P\right\} $$ Let's prove that no element of $P_P$ is a unit. Suppose
>   $a\in P$, $s\in S=R\setminus P$, $x\in R$ and $t\in S$ be such that $$
>  \frac{a}{s}\frac{x}{t}=\frac{1}{1} $$ By definition there exists $u\in
>  S$ with $u(ax-st)=0$ or $uax=ust$. This is a contradiction because
>    $uax\in P$, but $ust\in S$.
>
> On the other hand, every element of $R_P$ not in $P_P$ is a unit.
>   Indeed, if $a/s\notin P_P$, we have $a\notin P$, so $(a/s)^{-1}=s/a$.

I don't get why we have two direction prove here , isn't it enough to show the first direction only?

Comment: Pick $\mathbb Z$ and any ideal $I=n\mathbb Z$. Then no element in $I$ is an unit. Does this prove that $I$ is maximal ideal?

Comment: Oh I see.. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Let $I \nsubseteq P_p$. Then there exists some $\frac{a}{b} \in I$ with neither $a,b$ in $P$. But them, $a$ appear among denominators. Conclude that $1 \in I$